# Suggested library for grails 2.4.3 "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.1-grails-2.4" is not available

Tags: grails

In release notes for Grails 2.4.3 it is suggested to change `"org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"` to `"org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.1-grails-2.4"` but this jar is not available in maven repos. Is it a mistake or it is not yet available?

Also for new apps created with grails 2.4.3, library in BuildConfig is in old version

thanks

Comment: This is related to https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11533 but JIRA is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Brown has fixed the issue named the dependency correctly, per the bug below.  I verified that 
test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.1-grails-2.4" now works!

I had the same issue I fixed it by changing the dependency to 
test "org.grails:datastore-test-support:1.0.1-grails-2.4"
per http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.grails|datastore-test-support|1.0.1-grails-2.4|jar

Since the bug droggo mentioned was fixed I created a new issue (https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11622)